# How to animate particles spraying on an object

Tags: animation, particles

I'm trying to make an animation of the sun throwing up sprinkles on icecream.
I want to make the particles stick on ice cream as they fall but I'm too noob to figure it out.
I tried to make the ice cream both as collision and soft body but wasn't sure what to change.
Please help me :'( If this is an easy solution, let me know what to search for to find a tutorial!

[image]

Comment: Please research physics collision objects and friction and damping and drag.  There are many example of items follow on flat floor bouncing and coming to a stop.  That is a beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to make the particles stick to the surface (thanks to [Bibi09](http://blenderclan.tuxfamily.org/html/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=50381&forum=1)):

- Give your ground surface a *Physics > Collision*.
- Select your emitter object and in the *Particle panel >  Physics > Deflection >* activate *Die on Hit*, and in *Render > Extra >* activate *Dead*:

[image]